# Return different df based on condition

Tags: python, function

Have 2 dataframes (`foo` and `bar`), but only want to export the dataframe with more rows to a csv. Unsure of how to populate a function that does this. My assumption is that it could look something like the below, but this only returns blank dataframes for `x`.

```
x = pd.DataFrame()

def longer():
    if len(foo) > len(bar):
        return foo
    else:
        return bar

x.apply(longer()).to_csv('x.csv')
```

Hoping this is a quick and easy answer--thanks so much!

Comment: If "x" is also a df you should read the docs about "apply".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to export the larger DataFrame, it seems like this would be a lot simpler:

```
max(foo, bar, key=len).to_csv('x.csv')
```

Or if you also want to keep a reference to the larger one for further use:

```
larger = max(foo, bar, key=len)
larger.to_csv('x.csv')
```